# Why won't my article change color on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=fB8flQJ3Ef

My article class, download, won't change the background color on click, I'd like it to occur to anything marked with the class="download", but only on the specific one I clicked

Comment: jsfiddle link doesn't work for me.

Comment: I made it public, I don't know how to make it a private session based on link @TAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var download = document.querySelectorAll(".download");

    for(i in download)
    {
        download[i].onclick = function()
        {
            this.style.background = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

Thing is that you had : dowload[i].style which can't be used inside the event since it will reference outer "i" and as consequence it gives you errors..

Comment: THANK YOU, I'm not familiar with the array that was returned from querySelectorAll THANK YOU